# mongo aggregate result exceed maximum document size

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I use mongo aggregate function to find duplicated documents in a collection, where the collections looks like the following:

```
{_id, placement_id, placement_name, program_id, target}
```

I need to find all the documents that have exactly the same fields except _id and placement_id, 
so this two documents are the same:

```
{_id:3, placement_id:23, placement_name:"pl1", program_id:5, target:"-"}
{_id:7, placement_id:55, placement_name:"pl1", program_id:5, target:"-"}
```

The aggregate function I came up with is:

```
db.placements.aggregate({$group:{_id:{placement_name:"$placement_name", program_id:"$program_id", target:"$target"}, total:{$sum:1}}},{$match:{total:{$gte:2}}});
```

Then mongo just returned:

```
Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:15)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:897:9)
    at (shell):1:15
Wed Apr  2 07:43:23.090 aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",
    "code" : 16389,
    "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:898
```

the aggregate is correct, I tested it on a smaller collection and it works fine, but the production collection has about 80M documents. I was wondering when trying the find() function on 80M documents, it works  and asking you to type 'it' for more records. How come the aggregate function doesn't have this capability? I also tried to append limit() to the end of the aggregate function but it won't work either. Any work around? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> how come aggregate function don't have this capability?

It does in 2.6 which will be out very soon.

> i also tried to append limit() to the end of the aggregate function, it won't work either. any work around?

There is a `$limit` operator for the aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/

Comment: I have 2.6 and still get this error. Has it been added?

Comment: @jwillis0720 yes http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue there. After googling I found out that you can use the runCommand in Mongo to use the aggregation and set the allowDiskUse option to true, to use the hard drive as an extension of the memory. 
[enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/)

Comment: How will this help, if the resultant aggregation (which presumably contains all of the duplicated documents in the collection) exceeds 16MB (the max. size of a MongoDB document)? The error is not about MongoDB running out of memory.

Comment: @ddb I don't understand your comment. There is an upvoted, accepted answer already posted to this question. What Dagony posted is not the answer, as it doesn't address the OP's issue.

Comment: sorry, I delete it